# How to take the average of values of several HashMaps in Array of HashMaps efficiently?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a List of HashMaps

```
List<Map<String, Object>> arrOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
```

All the HashMaps have the same keys and the number of keys in all the HashMaps is same.

Now, I want to take an average of all the values of all the keys in the HashMap consecutively.

For example, suppose below are my HashMaps which I get from the array of HashMaps

```
arrOfMaps[0]={
A:1,
B:1
}

arrOfMaps[1]={
A:4,
B:5
}

arrOfMaps[2]={
A:4,
B:7
}

.
.
.
```

I want to have an average of A from 3 consecutive HashMaps i.e. A_avg = (1+4+4)/3, B_avg=(1+5+7)/3 and so on.

What could be an efficient method to do this?

Comment: Why is the value `Object` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: I have incoming HashMap with Object values that cannot be changed. I need to convert it to Double/Integer to take average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the average using stream:

```
Map<String, Double> average = arrOfMaps.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
             Collectors.averagingInt(value -> (Integer)(value.getValue()))));

System.out.println(average);  // {A=3.0, B=4.333333333333333}
```

Using [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) you are getting stream of entry set for all incoming maps. Next you are grouping by string key and getting the average value by each key using [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`averagingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) respectively

Comment: averagingDouble instead of averagingInt?

Comment: It's not clear they're actually `Integer`s. Might be safer to cast to `Number` and call `intValue()`.

Comment: @tank Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it's helped